# sending a POST to the Twitter API

Tags: c#, api, post, twitter, get

I'm lurning the usage of an API. Currently I successfully authenticated my selves and got all the tweets of a certain subject with a GET.
Now I would like to [favorite a tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/favorites/create/%3Aid). In the following code I use the post URL as in the example of Twitter. I get a 400 "Bad request" when I run it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public string PostJson(string apiUrl, string tokenType, string accessToken)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return responseString;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this library, it will save you a lot of time. http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/